# Some questions about NIO and socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, asynchronous, nio

Hello I'm currently trying to learn the NIO paradigm and have some question in order to understand better this way of coding.
In non-blocking mode :

- Why should I use a selector for the writing process ? why not directly use the write method if i have a hmi.
- how could I read a single line from a byteBuffer ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why should I use a selector for the writing process?

You shouldn't, unless you have had a zero-length write.

> why not directly use the write method if i have a hmi.

Exactly, that's what you should normally do.

> how could I read a single line from a byteBuffer?

A byte at a time. It doesn't have a notion of lines.